# There is only one submit button on a multi-row input to judging Null Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I have a multi row input form, but only one save button.

Page picture:
[image]

Page code:

```
                            <tbody>
                        {% for data in datas.get_execl_a %}
                            <form class="form-signin" action="{{ url_for('user.work1',id=data.id) }}"
                                  method="post" name="frm">
                                {% if  data.is_repeat %}
                                    <tr style="background-color: #ff3518">
                                        {% else %}
                                    <tr>
                                {% endif %}

                                <td><input id="a" name="a" class="input_a" value="{{ data.a }}"></td>
                                <td><input id="b" name="b" class="input_b" value="{{ data.b }}"></td>
                                <td><input id="c" name="c" class="input_c" value="{{ data.c }}"></td>
                                <td><textarea
                                        id="d" name="d"
                                        class="input_d">{{ data.d }}</textarea>
                                </td>
                                <td><input id="e" name="e" class="input_e" value="{{ data.e }}"></td>
                                <td><input id="f" name="f" class="input_f" value="{{ data.f }}"></td>
                                <td><input id="g" name="g" class="input_g" value="{{ data.g }}"></td>
                                <td><input id="h" name="h" class="input_h" value="{{ data.h }}"></td>
                                <!--<td><input id="i" name="i" class="input_i" value="{{ data.i }}"></td>-->
                                <td><input id="j" name="j" class="input_j" value="{{ data.j }}"></td>
                                <td><textarea
                                        id="k" name="k"
                                        class="input_k">{{ data.k }}</textarea>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="l" name="l" class="input_l" type="date" value="{{ data.l }}">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="return IsEmpty();" style="width: 60px">submit</button>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
```

I tried the following JavaScript code:

```
function IsEmpty() {
        if (document.getElementById('l').value === "") {
            alert("Date cannot be empty");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}

</script>
```

Prompt when all dates are empty

[image]

but other rows will not prompt even if the date is empty
[image]

I want to prompt every blank row.

Comment: seems like you have multiple submit button as well. only issue is form is single, which needs to be repetitive per row

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie yes, null values ​​can only be verified once,I need every row of verification